# Problem loading c# project in VS2003

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2003

By mistake I think touched some file (dont know the name) in the following folder..

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322

ever since then, I keep getting the following error...

Project 'xyz' could not be opened because the Visual C# .Net Compiler could 
not be created. Loading the .projdata file failed or the disk is full.

This has to do with VS2003 Professional

I have Googled and tried the following and failed....

1. uninstall VS2003. install VS2003.
2. Updated registry value HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VCSExpress\7.1\Packages for SkipLoading to 0x00000000
3. executed the command devenv /ResetSkipPkgs

All of the above have failed. I can not seem to load any C# project in VS2003. However I could easily load VB.net project in VS2003. My c# environment is really messed up.

Please help. I am desperate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to reinstall .NET 1.1, not Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks... I am installing .net 1.1 right now.. Will post back here if this solved the problem.. Thanks